# Phaser 3 array collison

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In phaser 3 I use overlap to check for collision. My code follows:

```
//bulletA is an array(one of the 2 arrays where collison is being checked) it contains all my bullet sprites
//enemy1 is an array containing all the enemies, which I am testing for collision with my bullets. It contains all my enemy sprites
this.physics.add.overlap(bulletA, enemy1, collide1, null, this);
```

The collision detection works fine(I tested using console.log on collision). However, I need to be able to tell which specific enemy sprite in the enemy1 array is colliding with my bullets. This needs to happen so that I can play an explosion animation on the enemy, and remove that specific one from the game. Is there any way to get the specific element of the array on which overlap is being used?

Comment: ArcadePhysicsCallback returns the object that did collide. https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/global.html#ArcadePhysicsCallback

Comment: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.ArcadePhysics.html#overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **overlap** function takes a callback that return the two collided object
https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.ArcadePhysics.html#overlap

For instance

```
overlap(bulletA, enemy1, collide1)

function collide1 (ob1, ob2) {
  // ob1 is the bullet that collided with the enemy
  // ob2 is the enemy that collided with the bullet
}
```

Comment: Thank You For the help! I didn't realize the function returned those values.